# insert complex line in html file from the command line/bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I use a bash script to add a javascript file to a directory, but after that I need to insert into the index.html this line at between line 30 and 31.

```
<script type="text/javascript\" src="./js/jquery.browser.js\"></script>
```

I used the following command in my but it doesn't work (it prints me the content of the index.html like cat would do) :

```
sed '30i\ <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/jquery.browser.js\"></script> ' /path/to/index.html
```

should I use perl? maybe sed directly? if so how? 
thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add option `-i`, to make it update the file, not write to standard out.

Also `30i` inserts before line 30, so you need `31i`. Also you inserted a single space, I assume this is in error.

So you need:

```
sed -i '31i\<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/jquery.browser.js\"></script> ' /path/to/index.html
```